# How to prove "The maps factoring through an injective object are precisely the null-homotopic maps"

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

Thanks for your attention,

I'm an undergraduate. I'm reading the book of Dieter Happel, *Triangulated categories in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras*, 
I cannot prove this sentence:

> "The maps factoring through an injective object are precisely the null-homotopic maps."

Here, the object is in the complex category.

Please give a complete proof or some references which take it!

Comment: You should describe the context in which that statement appears.

Comment: In any case, this follows from the very special form which the injective objects have: to see this, notice that you can describe precisely the indecomposable injectives.

Comment: It's not true. Where in Happel's book does this sentence appear? What is true is that the null-homotopic maps are the ones factoring through $\mathcal{S}$-injective objects, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the class of short exact sequences of complexes that are split in each degree.